# Spring Security Basic authentication for a single path next to token authentication

Tags: authentication, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication, spring-security-oauth2

I have a custom ResourceServerTokenServices in place:

```
@Configuration
public class CloudSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    protected MyResourceServerTokenServices() {
        return new MyResourceServerTokenServices();
    }
}
```

Then I have follogin ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityResourceConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);

        http.authorizeRequests().accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager())
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").anonymous()
            .antMatchers("/health/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/v*/api-docs").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().httpBasic().and().headers()
            .frameOptions().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    protected UnanimousBased accessDecisionManager() {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> voterList = new ArrayList<>();
        WebExpressionVoter expressionVoter = new WebExpressionVoter();
        expressionVoter.setExpressionHandler(new OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler());
        voterList.add(expressionVoter);
        voterList.add(new AuthenticatedVoter());
        return new UnanimousBased(voterList);
    }
}
```

Now I need to add basic authentication (with inMemory credentials) for one single endpoint (lets say /myEndpoint**). How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: [this](http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-basic-authentication/) example may help you

Comment: Just an idea, if you provide multiple authentication providers, if one failed (token authentication) it will search for another provider ( basic authentication).